# How can I have a value increase by multiples of 10 in the inspector?

Tags: unity

I have a number that I want to be editable in the inspector.  However, I want to restrict that number to be a multiple of 10.  I can always just go into the code and set it to the nearest multiple of 10, but I'd rather force it in the inspector.  I am willing to use an int, float, Vector, or really any sort that can hold a number.  How can I do this?

Comment: So you want 26 would be 30 and 24 would be 20 when you run the scene?

Comment: I want either a slider that only goes to 0, 10, 20, etc. or a field that either disallows invalid input, or rounds it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use `OnValidate` for this. It gets called anytime the user changes something in the Inspector, but only in the Unity editor, so it doesn't add unnecessary checks into a compiled build of the game.

```
public class SnapTest : MonoBehaviour {

    [Range(min:-50, max:50)]
    public float snappedValue;

    void OnValidate()
    {
        snappedValue = Mathf.Round(snappedValue / 10f) * 10f;
    }
}
```

This gives you a snapping slider like this:

[image: Example of the Inspector UI]