# How can I get game objects and prefabs to recognize modifications in enum values from scripts in the scene window

Tags: unity

I have made a script with several properties and enums that I attached to an empty game object. I am making changes to the values within the inspector, since they a public. How can I get the scene window to recognize these changes as they occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking solely about changes in the Inspector, you can use the [`OnValidate()` MonoBehaviour message](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html).

This is called in-Editor-only (including in & out of play mode) whenever an Inspector property in the script is changed.

You can use this to [validate and adjust the new settings](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/113377/39518), update other object properties to reflect them, or fire off other reaction scripts & events.

This will not be called in a standalone build of the game, so you can use setter methods instead to react to runtime changes caused by other scripts in your game.